# Sonar authentification failed

Tags: curl, sonarqube

I have installed Sonar 3.7.1  on jbossAS 4.2.0 with mysql server 5.6.14.  Everything is ok.   After installation I tried to log in and it constantly fails to authentificate with `admin/admin`.

I have trying to reset the password with sql I got from the Sonar docs  (as per the  Sonar FAQ http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Frequently+Asked+Questions   )

```
update users set crypted_password = '88c991e39bb88b94178123a849606905ebf440f5', salt='6522f3c5007ae910ad690bb1bdbf264a34884c6d' where login = 'admin'
```

I have configured some maven projets to point to my sonar mysql server and when I   run the goal `sonar:sonar` the project is well update in my sonar interface.

When I execute the request

```
curl http://<IP>:8080/sonar/api/authentication/validate -v -u admin:admin
```

the answer is :

```
"valid":true
```

And request :

```
curl http://<IP>:8080/sonar/api/users/search
```

answer :

```
{"users":[{"login":"admin","name":"Administrator","active":true}]}
```

I have also tried to drop the database and restart from scratch but always not work.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Do you manage to get this working when starting SonarQube in standalone mode? Please note that JBoss AS has never been supported.

Comment: When I start it in standalone mode it run very well. Thanks you for your help.

Comment: OK, so this has something to do with JBoss AS, and I can't help you on that unfortunately :-/

Comment: I also add this kind of error, but when trying to connect IntelliJ plugin with an old version of Sonar (3.2). The REST API has appeared since version 3.3 apparently (source : http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743649)

Comment: I'm using Sonar 4.3.2, Eclipse Kepler and Sonar Plugin 3.4.0. Seems the plugin is not sending the basic http auth...

Comment: I tried Eclipse Luna from a fresh download and the Sonar Plugin worked out of the box. Seems both plugin versions are the same...